# Help with simplifying this - where have I made an error

Tags: complex-numbers

$$e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}$$

$$e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1} \cdot \frac{e^{-i} -1}{e^{-i} -1}$$

$$e^i \frac{(e^{in}-1)(e^{-i}-1)}{(e^{-i}-1)(e^i-1)}$$

$$e^i \frac{(e^{in}-1)(e^{-i}-1)}{(e^{-i}-1)(e^i-1)}$$

$$e^i \frac{ e^{in-i} - e^{in} - e^{-i} + 1}{1 - e^{-1} - e^i + 1}$$

$$ \frac{ e^{in} - e^{i(n+1)} - 1 + e^i}{2 - 2\cos(1)}$$

How can I simplify this further, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: $e^{i(n+1)}-e^i=e^{i(n/2+1)}\left(e^{in/2}-e^{-in/2}\right)=2ie^{i(n/2+1)}\sin(n/2)$

Comment: $$(e^i-1)(e^{-i}+1)=\\=e^i-e^{-i}+e^{i-i}-1\\$$ I think  your mistake is ,that you put $e^{i}*e^{i}=e^{i^2}$ but it is not correct  $e^{i}*e^{i}=e^{2i}$$$(e^i-1)(e^{-i}+1)=$$

Comment: Hi darya, where have I done this

Comment: conjugate of $e^i-1$ is not $e^{-i}-1\\$ ,as we know $$e^{ia}=cos a= i sin a\\e^i=cos 1 + i sin 1 \\so \\e^i-1=(-1+cos 1) + i sin 1 \\$$ conjugate of that is  $$(-1+cos 1) - i sin 1$$

Comment: in your 5th line ,you did it !

Comment: ah, yes, that was a typo darya. in my workbook I've done it correctly, and arrived at the simplified $2 - 2\cos(1) $ expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following identity:

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

Using this with $a=e^i$ and $b=1$ will give you,

$$\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}=e^{i(n-1)}+e^{i(n-2)}+\ldots+e^i+1=\sum_{j=1}^ne^{i(n-j)}\\ \implies e^i\cdot\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{i^2(n-j)}=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{(j-n)}=\frac{1}{e^n}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^n e^j$$

Now, use the formula for summation of a finite geometric series.

Comment: Is that simply $$\frac{1}{e^n} \frac{1-e^{j+1}}{1-e}$$

Comment: @volcanomane, No, it'll come out as $\dfrac{e(e^n-1)}{e^n(e-1)}$