# How can I split this into its' real and imaginary parts, and simplify?

Tags: complex-numbers

Essentially, I want to prove that

$| \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}|$ is bounded.

If I obtain an expression for this sum:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}$$

I am not sure how to proceed to simplify and obtain some upper bound. (Is it possible to find a $\sup$ ?) This is from a real analysis course, and I have not dealt with complex numbers in a very long time!

I tried:

$$e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}$$

$$e^i \frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1} \cdot \frac{e^{-i} -1}{e^{-i} -1}$$

$$e^i \frac{(e^{in}-1)(e^{-i}-1)}{(e^{-i}-1)(e^i-1)}$$

$$e^i \frac{ e^{in-i} - e^{in} - e^{-i} + 1}{1 - e^{-i} - e^i + 1}$$

$$ \frac{ e^{in} - e^{i(n+1)} - 1 + e^i}{2 - 2\cos(1)}$$

How can I simplify this further, have I approached this incorrectly anywhere?

The numerator is hard to deal with :/

Comment: Can you show your finial numerator is (in absolute value) at most $4$?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with simplifying this - where have I made an error](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237136/help-with-simplifying-this-where-have-i-made-an-error/)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I did, but didn't quite feel the answers or responses got me any further.

May I ask, do you feel personally offended when someone reposts a question? I don't see why you are doing this :/

Comment: Please tell us next time what your real goal is (here: estimating $| \sum \cos(n) |$). Posting your own thoughts and results is great, but if you don't tell us what you really want to do it's hard for us to determine a) what you want, as in your other question, and b) whether you took a wrong/overcomplicated turn somewhere already.

Answer (score 0):

If a bound is really all you're after you can directly estimate your first identity, i.e.
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = \frac{e^i}{e^i-1} ( e^{in}-1).$$
For this note that $e^{in}$ are points on the unit circle, hence $|e^{in}| = 1$. Therefore
$$ \begin{align}\left| \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} \right| &= \left| \frac{e^i}{e^i-1} ( e^{in}-1)\right|\\
&\leq \left| \frac{e^i}{e^i-1} \right| |( e^{in}-1) | \\
&\leq \left| \frac{e^i}{e^i-1} \right| (|e^{in}|+1) \\
&\leq 2 \left| \frac{e^i}{e^i-1} \right|.\end{align}$$
The remaining terms are independent of $n$, hence you found your bound.

Comment: So would I just proceed as follows;


$$ \frac{ e^{in} - e^{i(n+1)} - 1 + e^i}{2 - 2\cos(1)}$$

$$ \leq \| \frac{ e^{in} - e^{i(n+1)} - 1 + e^i}{2 - 2\cos(1)} \|$$

$$ = \frac{ | e^{in} - e^{i(n+1)} - 1 + e^i|}{|2 - 2\cos(1)|}$$

$$ \leq \frac{ | e^{in}| + |- e^{i(n+1)} | + |- 1| + |e^i|}{|2 - 2\cos(1)|}$$

$$ \leq \frac{ 4 }{|2 - 2\cos(1)|}$$

?

Comment: @volcanomane Yes that is a good idea. Also note that $2-2\cos(1)$ is positive.

Comment: If I were to use the modulus on my summation identity, what would that simplify down to?

Comment: @volcanomane See my edit.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't the problem which I am working on, in its' entirety.

My goal is to show that $\| \sum \cos(n) \|$ is bounded, and I've just been using the fact that $\cos(n) = \mathcal{R}(e^{in})$

So, would I still be able to use this result?

Comment: Yes. You should start to think of complex numbers geometrically: If $z = x + iy$ is the result of the sum we have shown that $|z|$ is bounded, i.e. the distance between the point $(x, y)$ and the origin on the plane $\mathbb R^2$ is bounded. This also means that both $x$ and $y$ are bounded.